# How to check if type T is object or Array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Looking for a way to find out what type my genric is.

lets say I have this:

```
type person {
name: string;
age:number;
}
```

And I want to get the type of T where I call a function like:

```
const objResult = getType<Person>(); // Returns "Object"
const arrResult = getType<Array<Person>>(); //return "Array"
```

how do I write this?

```
function getType<T>(): string {
  // what to do?
}
```

Comment: @jebaa No, I just want to know what generic Type I have sent in to the function

Comment: I think you misunderstand that a generic is not a parameter and cannot be accessed at runtime.

Comment: You are calling the function without arguments. You haven't _"sent"_ anything into the function. AFAIK the runtime behavior can't depend on transpile time features. That's the answer in the dupe. From the accepted answer in the dupe: _"You cannot have the JavaScript that runs change its behavior depending on what sort of types can be inferred by TypeScript."_ Generics in TypeScript are different to generics in Java or templates in C++.

Comment: @jaba Please present this. I think this question is worth keeping and thank you!

Comment: What's the difference to the dupe? I can't find one.

Comment: I would argue this is straight to the point of the generic and not involving any SQL into it. I would argue that the question is more clear to the point as is your answer which I belive can benefit others